# Paste list of commands into PowerShell and cmd.exe produces different output formats

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a list of commands to execute.

```
echo now
echo and
echo then
```

When I copy/paste these three (3) lines into a cmd.exe window, the output of each command appears before the next command.

```
15:21:23.92 2023-03-13  C:\>echo now
now

15:21:25.76 2023-03-13  C:\>echo and
and

15:21:25.76 2023-03-13  C:\>echo then
then
```

However, when I paste this into a PowerShell console, all three commands appear, then the output appears without showing the command that produced it.

```
PS C:\> echo now
>> echo and
>> echo then
>>
now
and
then
```

When the list of commands is more complex and longer, it is -very- helpful to see the command immediately before the output it produces. Is it possible to have the same result in a PowerShell console as appeared from cmd.exe?

Please note, this is not a question about making the same commands work in PowerShell and cmd.exe. This question is about the order of output.

Comment: Use _mouse right-click_ or `Ctrl+Shift+V` for *paste* instead of `Ctrl+V`?

Comment: @JosefZ, `Ctrl+Shift+V` does not work on my machine.

Comment: It's configurable in PowerShell shortcut properties (*Options* tab).

Comment: @JosefZ, yes, thank you. That works.